# python dictionary, can't get correct value

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I can't understand one thing, explain please

If we have this code

```
import sys
from test import bye, hello


class Example:

    COMMANDS = {
        'h': hello(),  # print 'hello'
        'b': bye(),    # print 'bye'
    }

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = self.check(arg)

    def check(self, arg):
        return self.COMMANDS.get(arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example(sys.argv[1])
```

I run script `python test2.py h`
and would be logical if class return `hello`, because argument was `h`
but class return

```
hello
bye
```

How call function via dictionary key correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `COMMANDS` class variable should contain the function objects and not the results of the function calls:

```
COMMANDS = {
    'h': hello,  # print 'hello'
    'b': bye,    # print 'bye'
}
```

Then, `check` should invoke the function and return it's value:

```
def check(self, arg):
    return self.COMMANDS.get(arg)()  # () call the function object
```

Comment: Thanks, got it! we will get object via `key`, and when we retrieve object we use `()` in order call function, Am I right?